# How to Parse XML Descendants elements subtree

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

This XML is a bit different, 
Each node was originally `<dp41:nnnnn`  (i.e. their Type)  and ':' is invalid, so I removed those, leaving this.
When parsing it, it returns the entire element and sub tree.
So, the question is how to get the elements(nodes) from this xml.
The code used returns the entire subtree and specified parent node as one element
i.e.
from (including)..VehicleValueInfo ...+ all elements within and the close tag VehicleValueInfo />
Wanted is the VehicleValue'node's descendant elements.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <s:Body>
            <GetConvergedDataRequestResponse xmlns="http://autoi.trnsn.co.za/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <ConvergedData i:type="d4p1:ConvergedResults" xmlns:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trnsn.Auto.Convergence.B2B.BusinessModels">
                    <AccidentHistory i:nil="true"/>
                    <AlertInfo i:nil="true"/>
                    <CloneInfo i:nil="true"/>
                    <DiskDriveInfo>
                        <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                        <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                       <AirbagDetails>DRIVER, PASSENGER</AirbagDetails>
                    </DiskDriveInfo>
                    <EnquiryHistory i:nil="true"/>
                        <VehicleValueInfo>
                            <VehicleValue>
                            <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>              
                            <AdjCostPrice>0</AdjCostPrice>
                            <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
                        </VehicleValue>
                    </VehicleValueInfo>
```

Code is;

```
XNamespace ns = "http://autoi.trnsn.co.za/types";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants("{" + ns + "}VehicleValue"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
};
```

The output irrespective of Decendants or elements or a foreach within the first foreach is still the whole tree
which is (in it's entirety):

```
<VehicleValue xmlns="http://autoinsight.transunion.co.za/types">
   <ResultCode i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <AdjCostPrice>0</AdjCostPrice>
       ..
       ..
      <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
</VehicleValue>
```

I'm adding The entire Necessary only XML here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
   -<s:Body>
      -<GetConvergedDataRequestResponse xmlns="http://autoinsight.trann.co.za/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

          -<ConvergedData i:type="ConvergedResults" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trann.Auto.Convergence.B2B.BusinessModels">
               <AccidentHistory i:nil="true"/>
               <AlertInfo i:nil="true"/> 
               <CloneInfo i:nil="true"/>
               -<DiskDriveInfo>
                    <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                    <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                    <AirbagDetails>DRIVER, PASSENGER</AirbagDetails>
                    <Alarm>NO</Alarm>
                </DiskDriveInfo>
                <EnquiryHistory i:nil="true"/>
                <FactoryFittedExtras i:nil="true"/>
                <Finance i:nil="true"/>
                <MileageHistory i:nil="true"/>
                -<VehicleCodeAndDescription>
                    <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                    <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                    <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
                </VehicleCodeAndDescription>
                <VehicleConfirmationInfo i:nil="true"/>
               -<VehicleValueInfo>
                   -<VehicleValue>
                        <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                        <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                        <AdjustCostPrice>0</AdjustCostPrice>
                        <AdjEstCostPrice>0</AdjEstCostPrice>
                        <CostPrice>0</CostPrice>
                        <TradePrice>0</TradePrice>
                        <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
                   </VehicleValue>
              </VehicleValueInfo>
              <VesaInfo i:nil="true"/>
         </ConvergedData>

         <ResponseStatus xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" i:nil="true"/>

      </GetConvergedDataRequestResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Maybe the answer is to use descendants, which at least returns the whole tree and then try parse that result?

Comment: Nope:..tried an inner foreach using Elements
i.e.  var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(element.ToString());
foreach (XElement ele in xml2.Elements("{" + ns + "}VehicleValue"))
    {
     Console.WriteLine(ele.ToString());
    }
same thing, writes the entire tree to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the namespaces, this could be a solution:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
xml.RemoveNamespace();

foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants("VehicleValue").Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
};
```

Where `RemoveNamespace()` is:

```
public static void RemoveNamespace(this XContainer pContainer)
{
    pContainer.Descendants().Attributes().Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();

    foreach (var element in pContainer.Descendants())
        element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;
}
```

By the way, it seems the xml is malformed at line 5, position 69. I guess there is a missing namespace prefix declaration...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
XNamespace ns = "http://autoi.trnsn.co.za/types";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants(ns + "VehicleValue"))
{
   foreach(XElement ele in element.Elements())
   {
       Console.WriteLine((string)ele);
   }
};​
```

Comment: Nope: does'nt even iterate thru the foreach loop.

Comment: There was a double quote missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `xml.Elements` instead of `xml.Descendants`

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
foreach (XElement element in xml.Elements("VehicleValue"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
};
```

Descendants returns all the tree under the starting element

Elements returns all the direct children of the starting element

Comment: Nope: does'nt even iterate thru the foreach loop.

Comment: Your VehicleValue is not under namespace, remove it